Bluetoothd Error: Unable to Register Device Interface for 00:00:00:00:00:00
I'm experiencing an issue with my Bluetooth setup on Ubuntu. The journalctl logs show the following errors:
Jun 13 19:34:21 m bluetoothd[1941]: Unable to create object for found device 00:00:00:00:00:00
Jun 13 19:34:36 m bluetoothd[1941]: Unable to register device interface for 00:00:00:00:00:00 
Jun 13 19:34:36 m bluetoothd[1941]: Unable to create object for found device 00:00:00:00:00:00
Jun 13 19:34:52 m bluetoothd[1941]: Unable to register device interface for 00:00:00:00:00:00 
Jun 13 19:34:52 m bluetoothd[1941]: Unable to create object for found device 00:00:00:00:00:00
Jun 13 19:34:54 m bluetoothd[1941]: Unable to register device interface for 00:00:00:00:00:00 
Jun 13 19:34:54 m bluetoothd[1941]: Unable to create object for found device 00:00:00:00:00:00
Jun 13 19:35:13 m bluetoothd[1941]: Unable to register device interface for 00:00:00:00:00:00 
Jun 13 19:35:13 m bluetoothd[1941]: Unable to create object for found device 00:00:00:00:00:00
# etcetera

What could be causing these errors with the device address 00:00:00:00:00:00? I think this might not be a harmless error since Ubuntu crashes regularly when (dis)connecting bluetooth devices or turning bluetooth on/off.
Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Added info
When running bluetoothctl and scan on in the bluetoothctl prompt I do see a device that claims to have the MAC address '00:00:00:00:00:00'. However, there is no error message.
scan on
...
[CHG] Device 7E:1D:4B:0F:F2:BE RSSI: -77                                                                 
[CHG] Device 00:00:00:00:00:00 RSSI: -77
[CHG] Device 65:73:59:D2:2B:4E RSSI: -59                                                                 
...


A "MAC" of all zeroes is not a MAC, I'd say you might have communication with the device (sensing it being there) but failure to actually read the device config data.

Hmm... open a Terminal, type $ bluetoothctl (and Enter) at the $-prompt, then scan on and see what there might be... scan off to stop it, help for info... quit to exit

Thanks Hannu for the help. I added information to the question.

Well, I'd still say; that device is "broken" (maybe a flash chip/memory has gone bad) - probably not repairable (by user means); is it old, very much used or similar?

@Hannu It don't think it is my device, so I cannot tell. Any ideas on how to block it?
